# Display Multiple Form Submit Buttons Inline Same Line In IE8 In Table

Tags: html, css, format

I am trying to display two form submit buttons on the same line inside a table.  In IE7 the following code works great, however in IE8 the Delete button drops down to the next line even though I declared the form to display inline.  Any suggestions?

I created a basic test page here to show the issue: http://ajondeck.net/test/displayinline.html

Comment: I guess the problem is I need to include the input inside the first form.  I realize that this is probably not the ideal solution, but is there a way to accomplish this with tables?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't work primarily because your HTML isn't valid. You open a td, put Submit1 and then close a form element?? Fix that and a lot of problems probably go away.

If you want two buttons side by side, you should just be able to put them in the same container.

Comment: What do you mean, "put them in the same container"

Comment: Like in the same cell (td), div, span, p, etc.

Comment: right but they cannot be in two separate forms like my test setup?

Comment: Oh you actually want two separate forms? It's hard to figure out what you want exactly from your page because the HTML is pretty broken. Maybe you should restate the desired result.

Comment: OK basically as much as possible I would like to have the first form be able to submit the text box field, but also have the second form button sit on the same line (next to) the first form button.  Clear?

Answer (score 19):

Try the following because I had a situation where I made that work without tables and stuff.

```
//Put this in ur css styling area
.spanFormat
{
  text-align: left;
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

//This is the html that is used to make ur input buttons side by side on two    
//different forms.
<span class="spanFormat">
 <form action="someaction.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="action1" value="somevalue" />
  <input type="hidden" name="param" value="somevalue" />
 </form>
</span>
<span class="spanFormat">
 <form action="someaction2.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="action3" value="somevalue" />
  <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="somevalue" />
 </form>
</span>
```

That seemed to put both of my buttons on two different forms side by side.

Comment: This helped me a lot! I am not sure why this was not selected as the answer... but great post :)

Comment: This definitely should be selected answer! Helped me too.

Comment: Same as the above two comments

Comment: great answer. Did what I need!

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way I find is to use a little inline CSS (you could list it as a class in your stylesheet as well if you'd like) in the form tag, like so:

```
<form method="post" action="nextPage.html" name="nameForm" style="display:inline;">
<input type="hidden" name="value" value="someValue">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

put each form in their own TD.

ex:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td>
<form action="action.php" method="post" style="padding: 0; margin: 0">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="X1">
</form>
</td><td>
<form action="action.php" method="post" style="padding: 0; margin: 0">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="X2">
</form>
</td></tr></table>
```

etc.

Edit:  Just to be totally clear, you can also do this with one form enclosing the entire table.  On the next page (i.e. action.php in the above code), you can do something like:

```
if ($_POST['X2'] == 'Submit'){
    //do stuff
    }
```

Another tactic (if you have multiple forms) is to include hidden input elements and test for the values of those, but often you just need to know what button the user pressed, which is what the above code does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick solution you should enlarge the size of the td using css.

```
<td style="width:300px"> 
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit1"/>
    <form id="form2" action="www.test.com/test2" method="post" name="form2">
        <input id="Delete" type="submit" value="Delete" name="Delete"/>
    </form>
```

But the important thing here is that this kind of form is awfully coded man.
Try to read about divs and css, tables are your worst enemy!

Hope you find this useful: http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/examples/exampleitem/tableless_forms/P30/

Comment: I don't see how increasing the width of the TD gets me anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using tables for layout.  I think that whole "anti-table" crowd are just a bunch of 3l33t1st snobs.  ;-)  Tables are universally supported in ALL browsers.  They are from ancient days.  They are stable.  The are properly rendered by all browsers.

divs and spans are not.  There are significant differences between ie, ff, opera, safari, etc over how things like css styles (such as "padding" or "margins") are played out in the rendering of the page.

About your question:

An [input type=submit] outside of a form will do nothing.  If you want a button outside a form, you might try playing with "type=button" and see where that gets ya.  You'll probably need to script a javascript action to make it do your nefarious bidding!  ;-)

The other thing you might try is clearing the form's margin (by default, forms have noticeably large margins) and also try floating the FORM (ie, style="margin:0px;float:right;") or so....

Comment: Ah but a table cant be voice read in proper order like you can do with a div ;)

Comment: Html tables are for tabled data, divs etc are for layout. Sounds like you suggest using tables in both cases!